# Set Perforce MaxResults from command line

Tags: shell, perforce

I am getting cryptic error messages from a perforce server. I am checking out a Depot.

```
p4 sync                                                 
Request too large (over 3000000); see 'p4 help maxresults'.
```

I understand the issue, but the p4 help maxresults is a zero content manpage. Because it at no point makes reference how I can set this limit at the client.

```
export MaxResults=3000000
```

Is there any way to checkout the Depot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, you can't override max results; it's been set that way for a reason by your administrator. Here's the documentation: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.performance.html#d0e20714

Do you really need to sync more than 3 million files? If so, you may need to ask your administrator to add you to a user group which has a higher resource limit.

Alternatively, you can reduce the scope of your workspace by defining a more precise view mapping in your workspace definition. Rather than

```
//depot/... //my-client/...
```

set your workspace view mapping to something more like:

```
//depot/main/my-project/... //my-client/main/my-project/...
```

That way, you will only sync the portion of the repository that is actually necessary for your project.